# IIS 6: placing a text file in the root of an IP

Tags: iis-6

i have a a bit of a rather odd question and was hoping someone could answer it for me.

essentially i need to have a text file placed in the root of an IP address. something like **http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/textfile.txt**

the server is

- win2k3 sp2
- running iis 6.
- serving websites content using host headers.

any advice as to how i would be able to set this up?

Michael

Answer (score 1):

Yep. Set up a website to listen on that IP address only, and leave the hosts header blank (or, set the hosts header to be the IP address. I haven't tried this but the theory behind host headers should work). It will respond when the request comes through and doesn't match any of the other sites.

Comment: HI Farseeker, thanks for the advice, but unfortunately it didn't work?! any other suggestions

Comment: Did you try by the hosts header blank, or by setting it to the IP address? Are you acessing it through an external IP or an internal IP? The listening IP address needs to be the *internal* IP of the adapter, not the public external address.

Answer (score 1):

Open IIS, right-click your website node, select properties, select home directory tab. Ensure that read permissions are selected. Look at the local path and open it up in Windows Explorer. This is the directory that you will want to place your text file into. Once that is done you should be able to navigate to your site with the text file appended to the address (as you wrote out above) and have it load. You can also set this as the default page by going to the documents tab, clicking add, entering your text file, and moving it to the top of the list.