# Placing a text file in the root of IIS 6 server

Tags: iis-6

I need to have a text file placed in the root of an IP address, something like **http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/textfile.txt**

the server is

- win2k3 sp2
- running iis 6.
- serving websites content using host headers.

Any advice as to how I would be able to set this up?

Comment: Do you mean you could have multiple containers in IIS using the same IP Address and host headers? Yet you want a single text file to be browsed when you browse by IP address not by hostname?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IIS 6: placing a text file in the root of an IP](http://serverfault.com/questions/53686/iis-6-placing-a-text-file-in-the-root-of-an-ip)

Answer (score 3):

Look in IIS and find out where in the file system the website address resovles to.  Place your text file in that directory.

1. Open IIS
2. Click on Websites
3. Right click on the name of the website, and select properties
4. Click on theHome directory tab
5. view home directory path

Or you could FTP to the site and upload the file to the root of the directory that way.